# How can I make a DIV element Fixed but non-Scaleable?

Tags: css, html

Hopefully I'm asking this question right.

Basically, I'm trying to implement a drop down menu into my design. I've been looking around for help coding it, since I'm still relatively new to HTML/CSS and found a few great tutorials that I have altered a bit to match what I have in mind.

The problem I have now is that I don't want my stuff to be scaled what so ever. When the browser is resized, it moves my div holding my drop down menu. This is not how I want my design. Hopefully the description I wrote can help you identify what I'm looking for.

I have read that you can achieve this by using a wrapper div to set the resolution of the site. I have tried doing this, but it breaks my current code, at least the way I'm trying to implement it.

Here is an example of the display that I wish to accomplish:

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvXUK.jpg)

Below is snippets of code from my HTML and CSS projects:

```
 HTML:
<!--Nav Wrapper-->
    <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Final Cut</a>
            <!--Begin Main Div-->
            <div class="navMain">
                <!--Begin Sub Nav-->
                <div class="navLeft">
                    <span class="nav-titles">DBZ Final Cut: Navi</span><br><br><br>
                    <div class="navDropLinks"><img class="navIcon" src="images/general/site/4staricon.png"><a href="#"> Home</a></div>
                    <div class="navDropLinks"><img class="navIcon" src="images/general/site/4staricon.png"><a href="#"> Archived News</a></div>
                    <div class="navDropLinks"><img class="navIcon" src="images/general/site/4staricon.png"><a href="#"> About Us</a></div>
                    <div class="navDropLinks"><img class="navIcon" src="images/general/site/4staricon.png"><a href="#"> Contact Us</a></div>
                    <br><br><span>This is some random text that is describing the current article. The picture above will relate to the article. This is filler text.
                    This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.
                    This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.</span>
                </div>
                <!--End Sub Nav-->
    <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sets</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>


    </ul> <!--End Nav List-->
    </div> <!--End of Nav Wrapper-->
```

CSS:

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Serif, sans-serif;
    background: white;
    font-size: 62.5%;
    color: black;
}

.wrapper {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
}

.nav {
    list-style:none;
    width:940px;
    margin:30px auto 0px auto;
    height:43px;
    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;

    background: #014464;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0272a7), to(#013953));

    border: 1px solid #002232;
}

.nav li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:7px;
    border:none;
}

.nav > li > a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px; 
    color: #EEEEEE;
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.nav > li:hover {
    left: -1px;
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;

    /* Background color and gradients */

    background: #F4F4F4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4, #EEEEEE);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F4F4F4), to(#EEEEEE));
}

.nav > li:hover > div {
    left: -1px;
    display: block;
}

.nav > li > div {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 87px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    background:#F4F4F4;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.navMain {
    margin:-4px auto;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid #777777;
    border-top:none;
    width: 900px;

    /* Gradient background */
    background:#F4F4F4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE, #BBBBBB);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EEEEEE), to(#BBBBBB));
}

.nav-titles {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 3px;
}

.navIcon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

.navDropLinks {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px; 
    display:block;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.navDropLinks > a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    width: 288px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-right: 3px;
}

.navCenter {
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    left: 313px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
}

.navRight {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    width: 280px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

.navImage {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 275px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Im not see the problem as when i re-created it in JSFiddle it doesn't re-size - https://jsfiddle.net/bdevybss/

Comment: The drop down menu is fixed like so:

http://imgur.com/a/RYIRq

And that's the way I would like for it to display no matter the scale of the browser window.

Comment: So you want the drop down menu to always fit the screen?

Comment: Perhaps the best way I can express what I'm looking for is to show you a different site? If you visit this site (http://www.pokebeach.com/) and interact with their drop menu with a browser window that is small you can see that the drop menu keeps its position. I will also add another image from my code running in a browser that will hopefully explain what I'm trying to accomplish better.

This is what happens in a non-maximized window, which I assume happens at lower resolutions as well. This is not the effect that I want. http://i.imgur.com/mVO7O1u.png

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I see what you mean, it always stays inline and your doesn't ok, let me have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is fixed it will not react to the parent div. So to fix it make the wrapper fixed instead that way you can center it and your content will adjust around the parent i.e wrapper.

I made a new wrapper inside of your wrapper and called it navWrapper;

```
<div id="navWrapper">    
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Final Cut</a>
            <!--Begin Main Div-->
            <div class="navMain">
                <!--Begin Sub Nav-->
                <div class="navLeft">
                    <span class="nav-titles">DBZ Final Cut: Navi</span><br><br><br>
                    <div class="navDropLinks"><img class="navIcon" src="images/general/site/4staricon.png"><a href="#"> Home</a></div>
                    <div class="navDropLinks"><img class="navIcon" src="images/general/site/4staricon.png"><a href="#"> Archived News</a></div>
                    <div class="navDropLinks"><img class="navIcon" src="images/general/site/4staricon.png"><a href="#"> About Us</a></div>
                    <div class="navDropLinks"><img class="navIcon" src="images/general/site/4staricon.png"><a href="#"> Contact Us</a></div>
                    <br><br><span>This is some random text that is describing the current article. The picture above will relate to the article. This is filler text.
                    This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.
                    This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.This is filler text.</span>
                </div>
                <!--End Sub Nav-->
    <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sets</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>


    </ul> <!--End Nav List-->

    </li>
    </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and then added the css to it which you can see below.

```
#navWrapper {
    width: 982px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this helped alot!! I had to make a few more adjustments with some other tags but it's a lot more manageable and is barely noticeable. I'd vote up but Stack won't let me. Thanks again!